# Disable ConcurrentMergeScheduler in Lucene 3.5.0

Tags: java, google-app-engine, lucene

I need to disable ConcurrentMergeScheduler in Lucene 3.5.0, because it does not work on Google AppEngine due to limitation on thread creation - it is not allowed to create any thread.

Any hints how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, basically the merger can be supplied in IndexWriterConfig.setMergeScheduler(new SerialMergeScheduler());

After that it is possible to use RAMDirectory with IndexWriter in GAE.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful [Google App Engine uses multiple web servers to run your application](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime#Requests_and_Servlets). So a `RAMDirectory` does not work, however you can try a `GAE` specific implementation of lucene for google app engine, or use the [Google Search API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search).

Answer (score 0):

There is a GAE-Specific implementation of Lucene: http://code.google.com/p/gaelucene/